# Can I remove some of the hover functionality in Windows 11?

Tags: macos, windows-11

I've been a Mac user for 15 years (after being a Windows user for the previous 20).

I'm now getting a PC again and wanting to emulate a few Mac things which I'm used to. I've seen some videos covering some of the obvious changes, but I'm wondering:

- 1. Is there a way to disable some of the hover functionality in Windows? I personally hate when I hover something, it opens up or does something (unless it’s a menu item, but only once I've initially clicked to open that menu). I like the confidence of a click!
- 2. Is there a way to disable the normal <kbd>Delete</kbd> button and only delete if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>?

Comment: You can probably adjust the delay - see https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-mouse-hover-time-in-windows-11.3232/ - I can't test this, so not an answer, but if it works you can add your own answer based on the info.

Comment: "downgrade" to windows 10? as a Windows 10 user, I don't even know what you mean by `when I hover something it opens up or does something `

Comment: @hanshenrik I love how you clearly have no idea what they mean, but you pressume that it's only in Windows 11. My guess (!) is that he refers to the type of tooltip you get when you for example hover in the file explorer over a file for awhile.

Comment: Some of the hovers in taskbar can be potentially disabled using instructions here: https://www.wisecleaner.com/think-tank/459-How-to-Disable-Taskbar-Thumbnail-Preview-on-Windows-11.html Please let me know, does this link help you a bit? In my computer these settings did not help for some reason though. Alternatively, you may want to try this software, for me this software seems to be able to avoid excessive hovers in taskbar: https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/releases

Comment: One question per post please. This allows there to be one good answer to each question in each post. You can make more than one post at a time, and then each can get their own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows is not Mac. There is no native way I have seen to change how hover works. That functionality is built right into Windows.

   Furthermore, in Windows 11, there has been a move to display only what is needed. Hover and mouse movements get extra functionality. This is all by design.
2. Try AutoHotKey to change basic shortcut functionality.

Comment: This answer sounds competing/defensive ("not Mac"). Also it is sort of saying that "naturally" the user should not be able to configure their system, because these behaviours are "built into" and "by design". The latter should not imply the former at all.

Comment: Windows 11 was designed to provide simplicity so I do not understand your meaning at all.  And the OP was comparing to Mac hence my statement. So what I posted was correct in this case.